Terra package rast() Raster Stack
I have a number (21) of raster layers (19 WorldClim climate data, euroDEM digital elevation model [DEM] and Corine LandCover [CLC]) which I am trying to create a raster stack for.
I have used the Align Raster processing tool in QGIS to ensure the extent, dimensions, resolution and CRS are the same before importing to R. I found that the extents were not 100% the same, so used resample() to tweak them further and they all now have the same extent, resolution etc.
For the WorldClim variables, I loaded all 19 files and saved as one object, before loading the DEM and CLC individually and resampling. I am now trying to create a raster stack of all 21 variables. However I cannot get it to work, and get a variety of errors:
files <- list.files(path = "Rasters/", 
                    pattern = ".tif$", full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)

climate <- stack(files[3:21]) 

# avoiding the original DEM and CLC, also using raster::stack()
# as this creates a raster stack, whereas terra::rast() seems to     
# create a single SpatRaster

clim_crop_ <- crop(climate, (roi_extent))

# or just loading a single layer for the resampling

clim <- rast('Rasters/wc2.1_30s_bio_1.tif')
clim_roi <- crop(clim, extent(roi_extent))

# loading the CLC and DEM

clc <- rast('Rasters/final/clc_3.tif')
dem <- rast('Rasters/final/dem_1.tif')

# resampling

clc_resample <- resample(clc, clim_roi, method="near") # categorical raster
dem_resample <- resample(dem, clim_roi, method="bilinear")

# stacking

rast_stack <- stack(clim_crop, dem_resample, clc_resample)

Whether I use clim_crop or clim_roi I get the same issues - it is only stacking the first 19 (the WorldClim data).
> rast_stack
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 484, 561, 271524, 19  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : -10.66667, -5.991667, 51.41667, 55.45  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : wc2.1_30s_bio_1, wc2.1_30s_bio_10, wc2.1_30s_bio_11, wc2.1_30s_bio_12, wc2.1_30s_bio_13, wc2.1_30s_bio_14, wc2.1_30s_bio_15, wc2.1_30s_bio_16, wc2.1_30s_bio_17, wc2.1_30s_bio_18, wc2.1_30s_bio_19, 
etc etc

Alternatives I've tried include using a single worldclim raster:
r <- stack(clim_roi, dem_resample, clc_resample)

which returns:
Error in .local(x, ...) : 
  unused arguments (new("SpatRaster", cpp = new("Rcpp_SpatRaster", .xData = <environment>)), new("SpatRaster", cpp = new("Rcpp_SpatRaster", .xData = <environment>)))

and:
> r <- rast(clim_roi, dem_resample, clc_resample)

which returns:
Error: [rast] use 'c()' to combine SpatRasters

So I tried that suggestion, as using c() in terra can apparently create a raster stack and I got this:
> r <- c(clim_roi, dem_resample, clc_resample)

which gives:
> r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 484, 561, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -10.66667, -5.991667, 51.41667, 55.45  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source(s)   : memory
varnames    : wc2.1_30s_bio_1 
              wc2.1_30s_bio_1 
              wc2.1_30s_bio_1 
names       : wc2.1_30s_bio_1, dem_1, clc_3 
min values  :          6.1375,   -13,  -128 
max values  :         11.3500, 32767,    44

This seemingly only has 3 layers and is a SpatRaster, not a RasterStack (which I need the later for my analysis).
Any suggestions greatly recieved!
*edit
I am trying to run a Species Distribution Model with the sdm package. If I tried to use the r SpatRaster as the raster stack for the SDM I get the following:

response_3 <- sdmData(species~.,
gwts_spg,
predictors = r,
bg= list(n = 1000,
method ='gRandom'))


Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sdmData’ for signature ‘"formula", "SpatialPointsDataFrame", "SpatRaster"’

This works perfectly with just the RasterStack of the WorldClim data.

The equivalent of raster::stack() for terra is simply base R c().

Does this answer your question? Terra equivalent for raster::stack()?

hi L Tyrone - I have read this, however, it creates a SpatRaster with multiple layers, not a raster stack. Also, it does not stack the Raster objects I have, as the WorldClim data, when stacked and cropped to the extent I require, is turned into a rasterBrick which cannot me stacked with other raster objects rather, when I attempt this it creates a list.

If you look at the dimensions of your r SpatRaster, it reads 484, 561, 3. The first two are xy, the last number is layers. This is identical to the equivalent raster::stack() dimensions. In essence, they are the same thing. If you specifically need a RasterStack object - for instance, your subsequent analysis depends on a function from the  raster package - then please update your question with more details about the intended use.  It will probably be useful to update your question with more details either way. Thanks.

Hi L Tyrone - edited as requested

Ok, run r <- raster::stack(r), where r is the name of your SpatRaster with three (or however many)  layers. This will convert your SpatRaster to a RasterStack, then try your analysis again.

This worked for the single worldclim layer and 2 additional layerrs, however, again an error (when using pipe or not, same error) when trying to add multiple worldclim layers:

pred_stack <-c(clim_crop, dem_resample, clc_resample) %>%


stack()
Error in .local(x, ...) :
Arguments should be Raster* objects or filenames
I suspect that when WorldClim data is stacked (or in a RasterBrick, as is the case when it is stacked and cropped to an extent) you cannot stack additional layers to it?


What you are after is
files <- list.files(path = "Rasters/", pattern = ".tif$", full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)
climate <- rast(files[3:21]) 
clc <- rast('Rasters/final/clc_3.tif')
dem <- rast('Rasters/final/dem_1.tif')

clim_crop <- crop(climate, roi_extent)
clc_resample <- resample(clc, clim_crop, method="near") 
dem_resample <- resample(dem, clim_crop, method="bilinear")
r <- c(clim_crop, dem_resample, clc_resample)

In your question you are mixing up clim_crop and clim_roi.
r is a SpatRaster. You can coerce it to a RasterStack with
x <- raster::stack(r)


Thank you both, i've managed coerce the data as suggested and competed my analysis :)
